# Create Dots in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create dots in relative layout and then let user be able to draw lines between them through touch.Consider this, lets take two dots A1 and A2, user should be able to tap on A1 and then A2, resulting in a line drawn between A1 and A2.

[image: This is the kind of layout i want to achieve]
[image]

So basically my question is HOW DO I CREATE DOTS IN SUCH A WAY  ??, so that later i can reference them and use in java code.Its basically for a game i am trying to design.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several options:

1. Create a Drawable. You might even consider making a custom subclass in this case.
2. Write your game using a graphics/game engine such as libgdx.

Comment: Can you please tell me if I use a drawable, how can i reference these points into java, like usually we create Id's in xml and then reference them in java and then use it.So what I am asking is if i use a drawable, it will take the drawable as single png file, how would i be able to create id's for these points in the xml on the png file ??

Comment: @user3452275 You probably will want to create the Drawables dynamically in Java using an array or ArrayList.